# Why android manifests set values by attributes not the elements?

Tags: android, xml

I am a novice. I would like to know why android manifest files set the values by attributes not the elements? 
In this page, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html, it says "
 All values are set through attributes, not as character data within an element. "
But W3C school's XML tutorial suggest " Attributes are difficult to read and maintain. Use elements for data. " http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp
Can some one please explain to me why? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To a certain extent, the xml format (for both the manifest file, and for other Android xml files) is not meant to be directly edited - it is simply the output format that the GUI designer uses.

However, Android's xml files are at least far more readable than the equivalent iOS files, so be thankful for that.

One downside I do find slightly annoying when editing XML values in attributes is that there is no easy way to comment out an attribute, compared to commenting out an element which can usually be achieved simply by surrounding it with `<!--` and `-->`

Comment: "To a certain extent, the xml format (for both the manifest file, and for other Android xml files) is not meant to be directly edited - it is simply the output format that the GUI designer uses." I completely disagree. There's a good reason why the Android documentation extensively describes all the XML. It's intended to be used directly. Furthermore, in the past the GUI designer has been unusable for many complex layouts where directly modifying the XML worked. Note that the documentation page that the question linked to didn't even mention the designer for the manifest file, only the XML.